# How to get the sum/total of all records? ANDROID Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'd like to get the total of all records. I'd be getting the records from my meal_serving. I'd like to add up all the values. For example, please check this:

Meal Serving
1st row - 8 
2nd row - 2 
3rd row - 3 
Total is: 13

This is what I've got:

```
public String getTotal() {
        String[] column =
                new String[]{ KEY_SERVING, "sum(meal_serving)" };
        Cursor c = 
                ourDatabase.query( DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null, null );


    String result = "";
    int iSERVING = c.getColumnIndex( KEY_SERVING );

    for ( c.moveToFirst(); ! c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext() ){
        result = result + c.getString( iSERVING );
    }
    return result;
}
```

But only the last record is showing. What's wrong?

Comment: remove the first column from the projection and use 0 as column index. read the first result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do

```
String[]{ "sum(meal_serving) as " + KEY_SERVING };
```

Instead of your current column string array. That will generate the sum and name it so you can retrieve it.

You might need to make up a unique name if KEY_SERVING is one of your other columns too.